# How to get LogCat to be "sticky" at Debug time

Tags: android, android-logcat

When I flip into that alternate reality known as Debug time (the Debug Perspective of Eclipse becomes active), I want LogCat to always be there; it's not, and I have to open it manually/explicitly each time. Can I "train it" to always be there when Debug time rolls around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lower left corner, there should be an icon that shows `show view as a fast view` when you hover over it, click it then LogCat and dock it where you want. That works on my Galileo version's Debog perspective. If that's what you're doing and it still doesn't stay, try running eclipse in as administrator.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that; I always run Eclipse as an admin; the Irish have been utilizing the Debog perspective for many a moon now (for peat's sake).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  The answer , for me, was that all the items in the icon view at the bottom of the window occupy the same window. On the left side of the row of icons is one that looks like a couple of windows. Click on that and it restores the window to be fixed.

Hope this helps

Cliff